# table looping in not working jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(".btnclass").click( function() {
    var row = $("table").find("tr");
    $.each( row, function() {
        $col = $(this).find("td");
        $.each( $col, function() {
            var one = "1";
            var zero = "0";
            var $k = $(this).css("background-color");
            if( $k === 'rgb(15, 210, 15)' ) {
                s.push( one );
            } else {
                s.push( zero );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i'm new to jquery and i'm trying to loop through htm table
bt it's not working ..
i'm trying to check whether td is colored or not and push value according to that...
i searched it bt could not find it..
If anyone know hoe to do it..
provide me the link...
Thanks

Comment: add html mark up as well

Comment: what is `s` and from where it came? as you used `s.push(one);`

Comment: Your indentation was all over the place. It made it very difficult to see what was nested inside what. I took the liberty of cleaning up the indentation and adding some more whitespace here and there to make it more readable. Whitespace is your friend: use it properly and be generous with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplified your code like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //when document is ready
  var s= []; //a empty array declration
  $(".btnclass").click(function(){ // on click of button
    $("table").find("tr td").each(function(){ // directly traverse each td of table
      var k= $(this).css("background-color"); // get td backgrond-color
      if(k==='rgb(15, 210, 15)'){ // compare to color
        s.push(1); // matched then push 1 to array
      }else{
        s.push(0); // otherwise push 0 to array
      }
    });
    console.log(s); // check array
   });
});
```

Sample hard-coded table example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var s= [];
  $(".btnclass").click(function(){
    $("table").find("tr td").each(function(){
      var k= $(this).css("background-color");
      if(k==='rgb(15, 210, 15)'){
        s.push(1);
      }else{
        s.push(0);
      }
    });
    console.log(s);
   });
});
```

```css
td:nth-child(even) {background-color: rgb(15, 210, 15)}
td:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button class="btnclass">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: @Antony  glad to help you :):)